# Latest version of Emotion styled components not applying styles to elements rendered immediately

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, emotion

We have a few cases in our app where `@emotion/styled` is not rendering the styles for a component. The weird thing is, it is applying a somewhat class name to the component, yet the class has no associated styles, as seen in this image.

[image]

You would expect to see a green background for this particular div, but we don't see anything. This is also happening when we render SVG content directly in React and use the CSS `fill` property in emotion. The logo will *sometimes* appear all black as the `fill` is never included in the resulting generated emotion CSS, but other times it is. This later case usually occurs after a rebuild/redeploy of the app loading for the first time in the browser. After a refresh, it shows the correct fill. However, in the first case, it never worked.

In the first case, we initially had some react `useEffect` code make a BE API call to fetch some data, and we displayed that data in the component. *In this case* it worked fine, the emotion styles were applied correctly. However I refactored it to take a static value and render immediately (instead of the async BE API call), and now all of a sudden emotion styles **are not** being applied.

This only appears on staging environments which have a build, not locally which use the `<style>` tags to hold emotion content. We use the emotion babel plugin to build, but don't do server-side rendering.

This tells me there is something fishy going on with emotion and static/fast rendering at some point in the component tree. It seems that if we apply an async wait to the system, the styles appear, but otherwise they don't.

Any ideas what could be happening? Sorry I can't share any code but literally it is this vs. this:

```
// Static.tsx
import React from 'react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const Text = styled.div`
  background: green;
`

const StaticComponent = () => {
  return <Text>static</Text>
}

export default StaticComponent

// Async.tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const Text = styled.div`
  background: green;
`

const AsyncComponent = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setText('async')
    }, 1000)
  })
  return text ? <Text>{text}</Text> : null
}

export default AsyncComponent
```

Then something like this to render:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Async from './Async'
import Static from './Static'

ReactDOM.render(
  <><Async/><Static/></>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```